# Why takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef) in registerOnChange of a ControlValueAccessor generates a "View has already been destroyed"

Tags: angular, controlvalueaccessor

I have this simple ControlValueAccessor component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-input',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [...],
  templateUrl: './my-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-input.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [{ provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: MyInputComponent, multi: true }],
})
export class MyInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  private readonly destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef);
  readonly ctrl = new FormControl<string[]>([]);

  registerOnChange(fn: (value: string[]) => void): void {
    this.ctrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef),
        map(arr => (arr.length ? arr : null)),
      )
      .subscribe(fn);
  }

  registerOnTouched(): void {
    // nothing to do
  }

  writeValue(uuidsSelected: string[]): void {
    this.ctrl.setValue(uuidsSelected);
  }
}
```

When the component is destroy, I got the error: `View has already been destroyed.`

If I replace the register function by:

```
  onChange: (value: string[]) => void = noop;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ctrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef), // can not use untilDestroyed in registerOnChange
        map(arr => (arr?.length ? arr : null)),
      )
      .subscribe(v => this.onChange(v));
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (value: string[]) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
```

It work without error.

Does any one have an explanation?

Why `takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef)` inside a `registerOnChange` generate an error and not inside a `ngOnInit`?

Comment: Do you mind sharing a stackblitz repro of your issue ? I can't reproduce it.